# Get Fourier an and bn coefficients from fft

Tags: c#, signal-processing, fft

I have a signal which is periodic (think force acting on a specific point of a disc while rotating, for each angle the force is different, but over time the force at each angle does not change).

For the ease of data exchange I want to provide "the essence" of this signal as Fourier-Coefficients `an` and `bn`. Instead of 360 values (one for each degree of rotation) e.g. 10 pairs of `an` and `bn` should suffice without too much loss of accuracy.

[Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schnelle_Fourier-Transformation#Implementierung_als_rekursiver_Algorithmus) gives an algorithm for an FFT in pseudocode which I implemented in C# (never mind faster libraries for the moment, there is a satisfying element to learning something new and writing things yourself) and which returns results I would expect.

```
static IList<Complex> FFT(IList<Complex> f)
{
    if (f.Count == 1)
        return f;
    else
    {
        int n2 = f.Count / 2;
        IList<Complex> g = FFT(GetEvenElements(f));
        IList<Complex> u = FFT(GetOddElements(f));
        Complex[] c = new Complex[n2*2];

        for (int k = 0; k < n2; k++)
        {
            c[k] = g[k] + u[k] * new Complex(Math.Cos(-2 * Math.PI * k / (n2 * 2)), Math.Sin(-2 * Math.PI * k / (n2 * 2)));
            c[k+n2] = g[k] - u[k] * new Complex(Math.Cos(-2 * Math.PI * k / (n2 * 2)), Math.Sin(-2 * Math.PI * k / (n2 * 2)));
        }
        return c;
    }
}

static IList<Complex> GetEvenElements(IList<Complex> data)
{
    List<Complex> res = new List<Complex>(data.Count / 2);

    for (int i = 0; i < data.Count; i += 2)
        res.Add(data[i]);
    return res;
}

static IList<Complex> GetOddElements(IList<Complex> data)
{
    List<Complex> res = new List<Complex>(data.Count / 2);

    for (int i = 1; i < data.Count; i += 2)
        res.Add(data[i]);
    return res;
}
```

The intended usage of this code is thus:

```
int FFTSize = 262144; //Power of 2
IList<Complex> Fx = FFT(Enumerable.Range(0, 1024).SelectMany(y=>ForceSignalList.Select(x => new Complex(x.ForceValue, 0))).Take(FFTSize).ToArray());
//Signal gets duplicated 1024 times to give the algorithm enough periodicity to chew on and then the nearest (smaller) power of 2 of the sampling points is taken
for(int i=0;i<Fx.Count;i++)
{
    Fx[i] /= (double)FFTSize; //normalise the values
}
double a0 = Fx[0].Real;
IList<double> a_n = Fx.Skip(1).Take(10).Select(x => -2 * x.Real).ToArray();
IList<double> bn = Fx.Skip(1).Take(10).Select(x => -2 * x.Imaginary).ToArray();
```

Reconstruction should be as simple as `double f_at_target_Degrees = a0/2d + Enumerable.Range(0, a_n.Count).Select(x=> a_n[x] * Math.Cos(x * at_target_Degrees_In_Radians)).Sum() + Enumerbale.Range(0, b_n.Count).Select(x => b_n[x] * Math.Sin(x * at_target_Degrees_In_Radians)).Sum()`, but it is not. The result shows little to no variation over the target angle at all.

**Does this have to do with the rather high sample count and thus very small frequency increments in my FFT?**

**Did I get something obvious spectacularly wrong conceptually?**

This post probably could also go on math.stackexchange, but I figured that I would get more valuable hints for the concrete implementation here.